# How to update map markers based on an AsyncTask result

Tags: android, google-maps, android-asynctask

I have an asyncTask `CommunicationThread` which creates some Latitudes and Longitudes. I also have a map activity where I want to take the results of `CommunicationThread` update the marker based on these results. Here is the code of my map Activity.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Thread2ThreadInfo connectionInfo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    connectionInfo = SubscriberActivity.getConnInfo();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        Value currentPosition;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                Log.e("start", "new thread");
                CommunicationThread communicationThread = new CommunicationThread();
                try {
                    currentPosition = communicationThread.execute(connectionInfo).get();
                    Log.e("start", currentPosition.toString());

                    LatLng templt = null;
                    double lat = currentPosition.getLatitude();
                    double lon = currentPosition.getLongtitude();
                    LatLng lt = new LatLng(lat, lon);

                    templt = lt;

                    MarkerOptions a = new MarkerOptions().position(lt).title(currentPosition.getBus().getBusLineId());
                    Marker m = mMap.addMarker(a);
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lt));
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(templt, 13.0f));
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

`CommunicationThread` works properly and the data (positions) are send to the map activity. I use an infinite loop to execute `CommunicationThread` tasks and when new positions are avaiable, fetch them. I alse use a handler in order to avoid issues with infinite loop inside the main thread. When I run it, the data are sent succesfuly (according to the logs produced inside the loop), but the map appears as follows:

[image]

When I run it without the infinite loop (just for one position) it runs properly. 
Any other ideas?

Comment: Your onMapReady launches a ui thread looper infinite blocking loop (the `get` is blocking) which freezes your UI.  Easiest thing to do here is move your map updates to the `onProgressUpdate` in async task and have it loop forever OR implement a callback invoked from `onPostExecute` and update the map and launch another Communication thread.  Get rid if the main UI loop.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get a key for the Google maps api ?
if you didn't you have to get a key to use the google map in your application

please follow this link 
[Get an API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key)

Comment: Yes. I forgot to say that when I run it without the infinite loop (just for one position) it runs properly.

Comment: Try to set a listener for data change rather than using an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

**1. Missing or incorrect or disabled API key**

Seems to be most often. I recommend to follow [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/signup). If you finish all steps, issue persists and you're still unsure whether it could be the reason, clone official android samples, find the MapWithMarker sample (android-samples/tutorials/MapWithMarker) and test against it. If you run the sample and it shows the map correctly, try to exchange default API KEY for the one you own.

In such case make sure, you enabled it in Google API Console.

**2. Missing Android GMS version meta-data tag**

Your `AndroidManifest.xml` needs to define following metadata attribute:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

See the answer here for more details and official documentation.

**3. Missing user permissions**

In older versions of Android SDK, you had to explicitly set certain user permissions to work with Google Maps API correctly, for example:

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This is not the case anymore but I would recommend to visit official documentation to make sure you meet those version requirements.

**4. Requirement for OpenGL ES version 2**

In the past, there seemed to be requirement to specify following metadata attribute within `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-feature   
   android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"  
   android:required="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have all the requirements set up and the map works properly. I forgot to say that when I run it without the infinite loop (just for one position) it runs properly.